# Making plugin output customizable

Tags: plugin-development, templates

I am writing a plugin that will display a timeline of historic events, and I am looking for ways to make the output customizable. I was considering including a template/example within the plugin folder that can be overridden inside the theme folder. My idea was to make sure WP looked in the theme folder first for a customized template before resorting to the one I create.

If this is not good practice, let me know!

What functions can I use to do the above functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Shortcode with a custom output template:

You could try the following shortcode demo:

```
/**
 * The shortcode [history_timeline] with a custom output template.
 */
add_shortcode( 'history_timeline', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    ob_start();
    if ( '' == locate_template( 'templates/timeline.php', TRUE ) )
            include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/timeline.php' );

    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
});
```

where the shortcode is `[history_timeline]` and

```
if ( '' == locate_template( 'templates/timeline.php', TRUE ) )
     include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/timeline.php' );
```

means:

- If `/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/templates/timeline.php` is located, then it will be automatically loaded.
- Else: `/wp-content/plugins/history-timeline/templates/timeline.php` is loaded.

where we assume that `__FILE__` is in the `history-timeline` root directory.